# How do you turn off progress reporting for LLM functions?

Tags: user-interface, llmfunction

When you run simple LLM calls, a popup progress report appears in the UI until the process completes:

```
(*example*)
LLMFunction["what is the opposite of ``?"]["up"]
```

[image: Progress window saying "Waiting for OpenAI answer..."]

**How can you turn this off?** (It is quite annoying to look at when mapping results over a list of results.)

Some comments and things that don't work:

- It seems like a reasonable thing to do: For example in `NetTrain`, `Predict`, `Classify` you can set [TrainingProgressReporting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrainingProgressReporting.html) to `None`
- Something that doesn't work: Wrapping the call in [Quiet(http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) doesn't seem to change anything. (was worth a shot)
- Hiding inside of a `ParallelMap` seems to suppress this (i.e., the `ParallelMap` progress reporting takes precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica 13.3, `LLMFunction` and `LLMSynthesize` have an undocumented option, [ProgressReporting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProgressReporting.html):

```
LLMFunction["what is the opposite of ``?", ProgressReporting -> False]
```